# How to Customize AEM Touch UI Timeline?

Tags: aem

I want to Customize AEM Touch UI Timeline list, Means I need to add one more value along with existing one

Anybody knows where is the code for that inside CRXDE?

Comment: Can I ask for the use case? The timeline can be extended with limitations so use case will help formulating the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are searching for the header level Timeline as shown in the below image

[image: Timeline]

the following are the paths that you are looking for.

**Selection dropdown filter**
`/libs/cq/core/content/projects/jcr:content/rails/timeline/items/timeline/items/filter`

**component**

CORAL: 
`/libs/cq/gui/components/coral/common/admin/timeline/`
 and 
`/libs/cq/gui/components/common/admin/timeline`
[image: timelinecomponent]